# PowerBI - supports parquet format from adls gen1

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, delta-lake

Need to know whether Power BI supports parquet format as source from adls gen1.
Planning to use adls gen1 or databricks delta lake(supports parquet format only) as source to get data into power bi.Kindly suggest or please share any documentation link to get an idea related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Power BI does support both Gen 1 and 2 DataLake, however both Power BI and Azure Analysis service does NOT support parquet file formats. You will have to convert them to a text format, like csv or other delimited format to load them from the Datalake

If you are using Databricks, and you have created a table structure based on delta tables, you can connect to those tables from Power BI using the data bricks connector. However you'll only be able to access the tables when the cluster is running.

Some outlines are on the MS Docs site > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/datalakestorage

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Data Lake Storage connector in Power BI under Get Data.

[image]

For more details you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-power-bi)